# why does ui-select allow me to enter text?

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

Why does ui-select allow me to enter text, is this the intended functionality or have I broken it? Can I turn it off?

[image]

Link to ui-select https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, it allows you to enter text as it should filter the options in the drop down to match the text that you have supplied.

However, it looks like that doesn't work for you at the moment (from the screenshot), so it looks like you have an issues...

You can see the filtering in action if you go to the link in your question (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) and click on Demo.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not know english very well. But i'm try to use the method ajax man.
something like these

```
var yourFuction = function (queryParams) {
    return YourRequest('/requestName?name=' + queryParams.data).then(queryParams.success);
};

$scope.modelToEdit = $("#modelData").data("source");

$scope.searchClient = {
    multiple: false,
    allowClear: true,   
    initSelection: function(element, callback) {
    },          
    ajax: { 
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        data: function (term, page) {
            return term
        },
        transport: yourFuction,
        results: function (data, page) {
            return {
                results: data.data
            };
        }
    },
    formatResult: function ( item ) {
        return item.name;
    },
    formatSelection: function(item) {
        return item.name;
    }
};
```

Your function is your back-end request. 
Transport is your function.
results is the JSON that back-end send to you. You can change yours returns before the              return {
                    results: data.data
                };

The format is what appears on your input. Exemple: if you need to show the ID, your code needs to be return 'item.id'. If ou need to show any number you code want to be 'item.number'.